# Формула нахождения максимального значения border-radius

Tags: css

Есть блок с n высотой и шириной. **Нужно найти *максимальное* значение border-radius, то есть то значение, которое если увеличить то ничего не поменяется.** Вот например он после 100px дальше на загругляется. Вот как найти эти самые 100px? Ну можно и не 100.

Comment: `border-radius: 50%` :)

Answer (score 1):

По моему очевидно, что это **n/2**

```css
div{
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
}
#d1{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
#d2{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
#d3{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#d4{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id=d1>40</div>
<div id=d2>30</div>
Дальше круги:
<div id=d3>20</div>
<div id=d4>10</div>
```